# Wilson's Theorem - Why only for primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, factorial

Why is it true that Wilson's Theorem only holds for prime numbers?

I read a proof of it, and it did not seem to cater to that aspect of the theorem.

Comment: Have you tried with some non-primes? Do you see a pattern?

Comment: Because it's Wilson theorem

Comment: As the answer shows, a more interesting question is when you replace $(n-1)!$ by the product of those numbers between $1$ and $n-1$ which are coprime to $n$, in which case there is a similar result stating that this is either $1$ or $-1$, depending on $n$ (and one can also say when it will be which).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $m$ is not a prime, it factors into two numbers smaller than $m-1$, thus we have $m \mid (m-1)!$ and $(m-1)! \equiv 0 \mod m$ if those factors are different.

If these numbers are not different, then it is sufficient to have $\sqrt{m}$ and $2\sqrt{m}$ as factors. As we have $2\sqrt{m}<m-1$ for $m\geq9$, the only other case is $m=4$, in which case we have $(m-1)! \equiv 2 \mod m$.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: Unless $m=4$...

Comment: And you also need to consider the case of squares of prime number i.e. $m = p^2$.

Comment: Good catch, I fixed it.